# CruiseControl: jabber notification on first successful build after failed?

Tags: xmpp, cruisecontrol

I want to set up jabber notifications to report only first successful build after failed, and first failed build after successful. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CruiseControl.Net, you can use an xmpp publisher but there is no support for only notify on change type like the Email Publisher's ModifierNotificationTypes's Change type.
You can try to modify the XmppPublisher.cs code accordingly or try to modify the ConditionalPublisher.

See the following:

XMPP Publisher (GTalk, Jabber, etc.)

http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1257

CruiseControl.NET : Email Publisher

http://build.subtextproject.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Email%20Publisher.html

CruiseControl.NET : Conditional Publisher

http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Conditional%20Publisher.html

If you are using CruiseControl, you can use the jabber publisher but you'll have to create your own onchange publisher which can be based off onsuccess and\or onfailure.

See the following:

jabber

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#jabber

onsuccess

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#onsuccess

onfailure

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#onfailure

Comment: Yes, and if I am using TeamCity - then jabber notifications for first successful build after failed is supported...